# CSS translateY and ZOOM causing gaps between divs

Tags: css

**Reproduction steps**

Open https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/jOPPrWr in Chrome and zoom to `125%`
You can observe the gaps between `divs`. These gaps are not appearing when `translate` is `0px`

```html
  <div class="tree" style="transform: translateY(50px);background:red;">
  
    <div style="background: rgb(229, 213, 232);">
     Kamquats
    </div>
    <div  style="background: rgb(229, 213, 232);">
    Lemons
    </div>
   </div>
```

Zoomed to 125% and background red appears

[image]

Comment: I don't get any gaps, can you post a screenshot of what happens?

Comment: The gaps goes away if you use margin top. If you have to transform and this gap is an issue then set bg colour the same, but I wouldn't consider this a real issue

Comment: you could also set a 1px border color to fill out the minor gap

Comment: @MihailMinkov I have attached the image and you can see the background red appearing at zoom 125%

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it always appears as it should, the transformY definition shouldn't cause this it only moves the element vertically. The only difference there might be is that my screen has dual density pixels (I'm at 4K) so I am viewing this at 1920x1080p @ 200%. Do you have any other styles that might be affecting the final example?

Comment: @MihailMinkov Thanks for checking this. May be you are not seeing because of pixel density. I don't have any other styles apart from what mentioned above. I am not seeing this issue in firefox browser though.

Comment: @Huangism I have put a sample code here. In my use case is there are list of elements and each of them having different background. The exact issue I am seeing some white patches on zoom and scroll in between the elements. This is not appealling visually.

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy I know what you see and I saw them too, hence my first comment about how to deal with this but generally I don't see users using zoom unless they have trouble reading your site